# Can post-processing use topoSet and createPatch without screwing up the results?

Tags: openfoam, data-analysis

I would like to use [`patchAverage`](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.x/blob/master/applications/utilities/postProcessing/patch/patchAverage/patchAverage.C) to obtain the average pressure on an object that consists of multiple patches (due to different boundary conditions), however `patchAverage` only averages over single patches. As long as the constituent patches aren't shared with other objects, I could simply take the area-weighted average of each patch's average.

However, due to a dynamic geometry where the individual patches change area in time, this would become quite messy. So instead, my idea is to use [`topoSet`](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.x/blob/master/applications/utilities/mesh/manipulation/topoSet/topoSetDict) to define a faceSet and turn that into a new object patch via [`createPatch`](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.x/blob/master/applications/utilities/mesh/manipulation/createPatch/createPatchDict) (replacing the old ones, which are no longer needed after simulating).

Would `createPatch` correctly map the simulated fields to the new patch or would I end up with values being mapped to the wrong vertices? Or is there another way to achieve this? (I also considered using [`sample`](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.x/blob/master/applications/utilities/postProcessing/sampling/sample/sampleDict), which can obtain the values for multiple surfaces at once, but then I'd have to manually average, and I'm not sure this way I'd weigh the patch faces correctly.)

Comment: (Also asked at cfd-online.com: http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-post-processing/105151-can-post-processing-use-toposet-createpatch-without-screwing-up-results.html#post373187)

Comment: I think CFD-online is a better place for this question. The patches are different at each timestep? Then you'll have a lot of fun with createPatch. I (but that is me) would go for a solution with swak4Foam (funkyDoCalc if you want the evaluation as a postprocessor. A functionObject if you want it during the run).

Comment: @bgschaid in this case I agree with you, I still wanted to see whether I might get some input here. I'll have a look at [swak4Foam](http://www.openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Contrib/swak4Foam), thanks